# Php checkboxes to rows

Tags: php, checkbox, mysqli

I need to insert each checkbox to row in MySql.

At the moment i am able to catch only one checkbox, but I usually have them 1 - ... who knows how many..

All my checkboxes come from Db like that :

```
<input type="checkbox" name="lisateenus[]" value="<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>">
```

On insert it should take the "page id" what is created and after that insert checkbox values to table.

it gets all needed ID-s but it inserts only one checkbox what is checked..

```
         $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
    if($result) {
            $last_id = $con->insert_id;
            $error = "Uus Teenus lisatud! ". $last_id;


            $checkBox = implode(',', $_REQUEST['lisateenus']);
            $query="INSERT INTO lisateenuse_seos (p_id, l_id, lisaja) VALUES ($last_id,'" . $checkBox . "','1')";     
            mysqli_query($con, $query) or die (mysql_error() );
            echo "Complete";


        } else {
            $error = "Teenuse lisamine ei õnnestunud";}
```

So everything is working exept that it only inserts one row, but 3 rows are checked and should be inserted..

Comment: So you insert only one row, and in the l_id every checkbox value is inserted imploded by ","? And you want 3 rows, where l_id is only one checkbox value?

Comment: each checkbox has his own ID (different) only last_id and lisaja have the same id, so each checkbox should be separate row in MySql table (after insert)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"each checkbox has his own ID (different) only last_id and lisaja have the same id, so each checkbox should be separate row in MySql table (after insert)"

In that case, you actually don't want to implode your checkboxes, but go through with a foreach on them:

```
foreach ( $_REQUEST['lisateenus'] as $somevalue ) {
$query="INSERT INTO lisateenuse_seos (p_id, l_id, lisaja) VALUES ('$last_id' ,'" . $somevalue . "','1')";     
            mysqli_query($con, $query) or die (mysql_error() );
            echo "Complete";
}
```

This should insert a new row for each checked checkbox. Using implode actually makes a single string from the whole array, which then you insert only once. With foreach, you send and insert command to the sql for each ( :D ) checked checkbox.

(I added some extra quotes for the good cause.)

Comment: babah, works like charm. Also now make sense.. ecah checkbox separate row.. and i did not even loop them -.-

Thank you.

Comment: These checkboxes are apparently whacky creatures, a similar things happened yesterday: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48929936/get-the-id-of-the-selected-check-box/48930201#48930201